# Options when improperly expelled from Schengen

Tags: schengen, removal

Currently in Spain but ordered to leave.  Reviewing an application which included photocopy of passport, someone found my entry stamp from a year ago, but failed to find the entrance stamp into U.K. within the ninety days (would have been 89 were it not for bus delays).  I have other evidence beside the exit stamp (ATM records).  Sent a letter to the hotel denying the application and ordering me out of Spain.  Doesn't say out of Schengen, and last I heard, Schengen countries don't share data on entries and exits.  But if I don't leave on my own and get "escorted" out, not only do I lose some flexibiity in where, I also get a police record, which **is** shared.

Someone asked for an image, but I don't see how to upload it.  Putting it somewhere that identifies me is not going to happen.  Downvote my paranoia if you wish.  I read Spanish so I know what thye letter says.

It allows two months for appeal, but the appeal has to be done here, and the removal order is fifteen days.  A local lawyer will appeal for free, but he's not available until eight days after I received the letter, fifteen days after it was written.

So I'm trying to figure out what to do if the appeal goes too slowly.

Ironically, I applied for NIE because multiple bankers said you can't open an account without it, and multiple realtors said you can't buy or rent without a bank account and an NIE.  Other expats said the same things.  But the day I got the letter, I signed a contract with neither at another realtor's office, and the next day a different banker said using a passport number instead of an NIE is fine.

Andorra has agreed to not admit anyone inadmissible to Spain.  Monaco is part of Schengen.  But it seems that I would be safe in Gibraltar, San Marino, or Vatican.  Anyone here know a reason why that's not the case?

Comment: "Found"? At the airport? At a police station? Why didn't you show them your UK stamp?

Comment: Individual countries are free to define their immigration laws as they see fit. Andorra, Vatican, San Marino and Gibraltar are not signatories to the SCHENGEN agreement and/or are only considered **de facto** members. All you can do is file an appeal and wait.

Comment: You can redact your removal notice and upload it with a view to getting a higher quality answer.  See http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-do-i-upload-an-image Normally we do Schengen refusals, but removals will work also.

Comment: Fixed tags, took out 'deportation' (which doesn't apply) and added 'removal' (which is the case here).

Comment: @SheikPaul: Could you stop SHOUTING each time you mention Schengen, please?

Comment: Unclear?  Too much distracting info? Should I edit OUT everything except "trying to figure out what to do if the appeal goes too slowly" and the last paragraph?

Comment: @Henning Makholm I am sorry, I will try. I didn't know it was that offensive or irritable. I previously thought it was an acronym like NAFTA, forgetting it is named after a town.

Comment: @JohnDoe Not sure the question is fully on-topic but as it stands, everything is unclear, what's your current status and citizenship and what are you aiming for? What makes you think your appeal will succeed? What have you appealed exactly? What you do if the appeal goes too slowly is go back to your usual country of residence and wait it out there. Going to some European micro-state is unlikely to be of much help.

Comment: Finding a qualified immigration lawyer to advise you seems like a prudent course of action. If the one who will work for free isn't available, is there one who works for money?

Comment: You wrote "Putting it somewhere that identifies me is not going to happen". We would never propose such a thing? Where did you get that silly idea? Did you read the link I gave? If you are looking for random, uninformed answers take your question to a discussion forum. There are dozens of them out there.

Comment: @SheikPaul you told us you had studied immigration law, today you think Schengen is an acronym? What gives?

Comment: @Gayot Fow What gives is the fact that most humans sometimes forget things which are not particularly significant like whether something is an acronym or name. Capiche?

Comment: Seems clear enough to me.  Told to get out of Spain, thinks it is unjustified,  and (probably) wants to avoid spending a lot of money to get back home if some place closer will work.  @GayotFow: The answer at the link you gave suggests uploading to imgur, which does demand identification.  Probably could be faked, but OP may not know that.

Comment: @WGroleau the OP has (apparently) abandoned the question due to his admitted paranoia, or neurosis, or whatever other issue that compounds his removal problems. We can't help drive-bys that are unable to describe their situation. In the meantime, about identification, put this gem into your bag of tricks and enjoy :)  https://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html?dswid=5332

Comment: @pnuts: depends on how long the OP wanted to stay.  Then again, since it relates to the 90/180 rule, I'd say leave it here.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/does-time-spent-in-non-schengen-european-microstates-count-against-the-available suggests that days in all these countries do not count for the ninety (if you can prove it).  But being ordered to leave would be a different thing, I guess.