# Can I register my exit from Italy when traveling to San Marino?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, italy, passport-stamps, san-marino

I am a non-EU passport and I do not need a visa for either Schengen countries or San Marino. I want to travel and stay in San Marino for a few days, and I would like these days to *not* count towards the limit of 90 days in Schengen area (because well, San Marino is not a part of Schengen area). How can I register the fact that I have exited the Schengen area with the authorities (i.e. get an exist stamp in passport)?

Related issue: how do citizens and permanent residents of San Marino prove they have not overstayed in Schengen area (it's interesting because the only way to travel to San Marino is through a Schengen country)

Comment: See also [Does time spent in non-Schengen European microstates count against the available 90-day Schengen time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68836/3221) for additional information beyond the suggested duplicate.

Comment: No, you can't since there are no border contols - thus no exit/enter stamps. Their citizens are treated as Italian within Italy.

Comment: It is legal to use 90 days, but you should not aim (plan) for 90 days. In case of unforeseen circumstances (which is one of the nice thing on traveling), it could create problems an high costs.