# For the Single Entry Schengen visa, do the microstates (Monaco, San Marino and the Vatican City) count?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, vatican-city

If a person has a Single Entry Schengen visa, would a visit to those microstates count as having left the Schengen area?

I know that Monaco, San Marino and the Vatican City count as de facto Schengen, but since they 'stop the clock' for the counting of the 90/180 days rule (per [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/does-time-spent-in-non-schengen-european-microstates-count-against-the-available)) for time spent there, I wonder whether they just consider it also an exit of the Schengen area.

The question is concretely about the Vatican, the other states might be of interest for OP with a similar problem.

It would be quite a hassle getting stuck in the Vatican. There's only one hotel there (Residenza Paolo VI), with prices in the €125-€320 range. but again, it would also be a pity to visit Rome and not visit the Vatican.

Comment: Yes for sure, I went there myself with a Schengen visa.

Comment: Point to note: it wouldn’t just be done with staying in a hotel in the Vatican. You would also have to avoid re-entering Schengen, meaning taking a helicopter from the Vatican either to a non-Schengen airport or to a Schengen airport that is content with treating you as a non-Schengen passenger.

Answer (score 25):

For almost all non European Union/EEA citizens, an entry or exit stamp is mandatory upon crossing the external Schengen border

- Article 8 (3) Border Code (**thorough check**)
- Article 11 (3) Border Code

  - (e) Citizens of Andorra, Monaco and San Marino are exempted

No 'Immigration' (enter/exit) stamp **for persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union law**

- Article 8 (2) Border Code (**minimum check**)
- for third country citizens: only when the **residence card** is presented

---

A Single Entry Schengen visa is considered used

- when an Schengen entry/exit stamp exists

so where there is no passport control, no new Schengen entry/exit stamp can be given and the 90/180 days rule apply (the clock does **not** stop).

---

**Monaco** is considered to be **inside** the external Schengen Border

- Convention on Good Neighbourly Relations of 18 May 1963 on the entry, stay and establishment of foreigners in Monaco and exchange of letters from 15 December 1997

  - France will stamp the passport when needed

    - when the external Schengen Border **through** Monaco is crossed

**Andorra** is considered **outside** the Schengen Area

- a multiple entry Schengen Visa is required to enter Andora

**San Marino** is considered **outside** the Schengen Area

- but maintains an open border with Italy, so there is no passport control

**Vatican** is considered **outside** the Schengen Area

- but maintains an open border with Italy, so there is no passport control

---

**References**:

- [2012 Obstacles to access by Andorra, Monaco and San Marino to the EU's Internal Market and Cooperation in other Areas](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=SWD:2012:0388:FIN:EN:HTML)

Comment: "For almost all non European Union citizens, an entry or exit stamp is mandatory upon crossing the external Schengen border": yet there are no facilities whatsoever to provide these stamps for people going to Monaco, San Marino, or the Vatican.  Yet these borders fall under the definition of "external border" in the Schengen codes.  How does one reconcile these facts?

Comment: @phoog Monaco is part of the French Custom area. And Italy, since WW2, performs no passport controls for the other 2. The EU Members had desided that the Micro states should not be members to keep the number of members lower and everyday things less complicated.

Comment: Being part of a customs area is irrelevant to immigration controls; just look at the UK and Ireland for example: both are *also* part of the same customs area as France.  I imagine that there is some explicit provision concerning micro states in the immigration control laws, either of the EU or of the national law of the EU member states whose territory encloses them, but I have not been able to find it.

Comment: In any event, this recitation of facts does not answer the question.  For example, Vatican is outside Schengen, but there's no border control.  This leaves me wondering whether a visit to Vatican city would count for the purpose of a single-entry visa, which was the original question.

Comment: @phoog The present status is the 2012 link that I have just added.

Comment: @phoog Since the days are counted based appon entry/exit stamps,  that won't be given, they have not left officialy. This is part of the **pragmatic approach** meantioned in the 2012 document.

Comment: Is the first sentence "non European Union citizens" or "non Schengen member citizens"? Also, is this true for all European Union countries that are not Schengen members (I know it's true for the UK).

Comment: @StewieGriffin For European Union citizens there is only a check of Citizenship, thus no 'Immigration' enter/exit stamp. To be precise : **for persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union**

Comment: Most note that entering to Andorra is quite fluid from either France or Spain and it is very, very rare to have you show your passport.

Comment: @fedorqui that may be true, but it does not change the fact that it a legal requirement. Peaple are not always fined for crossing a pedestrian red light but that **does not** make it legal.

Comment: @MarkJohnson absolutely! Just sharing the experience on crossing by car and having the feeling that it is like entering into any Schengen area country. But yes, from the legal aspect it is good that your answer states the facts which is that a multiple entry visa is required.

Comment: @phoog "How does one reconcile these facts?" I will probably be considered a **proportionate** responce to the  given situation. Proportionate is a word often used in rthe Border Code, just as **pragmatic** is used in the 2012 document. Both words may not be often used in law, but may be the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: @StewieGriffin EU citizens and nationals of Schengen-area countries all enjoy a right of free movement in both the Schengen area and the EU.  In contrast to Mark Johnson's comment, when crossing a controlled border they are subject to more than just a check of citizenship: there is also verification of the person's identity and of the validity and authenticity of the travel document, and there are database lookups to determine whether the person is a threat to "public policy, internal security, public health or international relations."  But they don't get a stamp.

Comment: @MarkJohnson "but that does not make it legal": what is someone who needs a stamp to do if the border crossing is neither closed nor attended?  I once crossed from Italy to Switzerland (not yet a member of the Schengen area) very early in the morning in order to catch a flight in Zurich.  There were no officers in the booth.  Was I supposed to wait until they arrived?  It sounds like Andorra leaves its border posts unattended even in the middle of the day.  What does one do in that case?

Comment: @phoog That depends on the local laws. In the older times, crossing mountain paths between austria and germany was allowed. On the land border between france and germany it was allowed where a passport was not needed. For citizens that required a passport, France did not allow the use of the green border crossings (passports were checked in hotels for the entry stamp andvrepoted to the Gedarmarie if missing). In the end you are required to obey the law, if you don't you will be held responsible. What happend to th UK citizens at the Canadian/US proves the case.

Comment: @StewieGriffin phoog forgot (for some strange reason)  to add the **However, on a non-systematic basis,... border guards may consult...** part of paragraph 3 of Article 8 (2) Border Code (minimum check) mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Mark Johnson's comment explains his omission: his source for the Schengen Borders Code is obsolete.  The [latest consolidated version](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407), now over two years old, reads "On entry and on exit, persons enjoying the right of free movement under Union law shall be subject to the following checks:...."

Answer (score 14):

There are no passport controls to enter Vatican City.

Technically, the Vatican is not part of the Schengen Zone or the EU, but it has an open border with Italy, and Italy is the only way to enter the Vatican.

So no-one will even know you have visited Vatican.

As *o.m* mentioned:

> it is more like "they have a practical agreement that the Vatican doesn't count." It would only really matter if someone stays more than 90 days in Schengen-plus-Vatican.

Comment: This is quite true, so +1.  One wonders, though, if someone on a Schengen single-entry visa were arrested in Vatican city what the Italian authorities would make of it when the person was to be transferred to them.

Comment: And it would be a fringe scenario, but Schengen countries might establish border controls if they with to.

Comment: So, your answer is basically, "you won't get caught?"

Comment: @QuoraFeans So yeah, they don’t know you’ve entered and some can view it part of the Schengen area

Comment: @QuoraFeans, it is more like "they have a practical agreement that the Vatican doesn't count." It would only really matter if someone stays more than 90 days in Schengen-plus-Vatican.

Comment: @o.m., no, the problem is that the visa is single entry. If you get an exit stamp on this passport the visa is void.

Comment: @QuoraFeans If I recall correctly it's actually that the *entry* stamp uses up the visa, so if someone with an entry stamp manages somehow to leave the Schengen area without getting an exit stamp, that does not mean that the visa remains valid.

Comment: @QuoraFeans With the entry stamp the Single Entry visa has been *used* (not void), since any other conditions of the visa are still valid (duration, validity, purpose). Void: was never valid at any point.

Comment: @QuoraFeans, I think you're technically wrong about stamps using up visa. **Exits and entries** use up visa, and stamps are one piece of evidence that one entered or left. At times others are more relevant, but those are special cases.

Comment: @phoog The Italian authorities will probably think that it is a  proportionate measure **not** to execute passport controls within the city limits of Rome and not give it any further thought.

Comment: @phoog With Vatican city being such an important tourist attraction, my guess is that no month goes by without that happening, nor does one pass where anyone bats an eye at what is technically an incongruency in the system.

Comment: @Jasper of course.  But it seems that this question is designed to elicit an explicit provision in some treaty or other legal document if one exists.  There probably is one, because t's very unlikely that the legal status of visitors to Vatican city is left to the whims of Italian authorities regarding border controls, but no answer has identified one.

Comment: @phoog I wouldn't be surprised if it was entirely unofficial provisions that go back hundreds of years (since it essentially boils down to policies that would probably have been similarly weird before Schengen). Nonetheless, you're right it would be nice to definitively know what the provisions are.

Comment: @Jasper the present relationship between Italy and Vatican City only goes back 90 years to the Lateran Treaty, signed in 1929.  Before that, the relationship was hostile, but I do not know what border control formalities existed, if any.  Still, I imagine there is something explicit either in the treaty itself or subsequent to it.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for educating me.

Comment: I would add that yourself, when in Rome, you will be hard pressed to know when you entered Vatican and left Italy. The limits are not displayed anywhere, and only careful observation of a plan will tell you one street is in Italy and the next in Vatican.

Comment: @Martigan: The spirit of your comment is correct, but in practice this only holds about entering or exiting St Peter's square: the rest of Vatican City is enclosed by high walls and guarded gates.

Comment: @DaG You are right. I however suppose that the OP is going to enter via St Peter square.