# border controls for Andorra and other micro states?

Tags: schengen, andorra, micro-states

I've seen several mentions here of the lack of border control in Andorra, and indeed, I saw none when I entered nor when I left.  But a web search finds a lot of pages stating they do maintain border control and none (that I saw) saying the opposite.

Several sources make Monaco, San Marino and the Vatican City "de facto" members due to reduced or no border control, but when I tried to add Andorra in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), it was reverted on the grounds it needed a citation.  (though the citation for the other three is a 404.)

**Anything official for Andorra or the other three?**

Comment: Last time I checked, maybe 2 years ago, you could see customs booths in street view images.  Whether they pay attention to immigration status, I couldn't say for certain, but I've heard of people with single-entry Schengen visas getting into trouble because they were on a bus that went through Andorra.

Comment: The 2012 summary is the only source I know of. [2012: EU relations with Andorra, Monaco and San Marino](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=COM:2012:0680:REV1:EN:HTML) *2.2.2. Schengen: Andorra is not part of the Schengen area. Border controls are carried out at the borders between Andorra and its neighbours France and Spain. ...*  [90 180 visa rules - Does time spent in non-Schengen European microstates count against the available 90-day Schengen time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/139802/95267)

Comment: Are you referring to immigration controls (passport/visa checks) or customs controls, or both? I’m pretty sure French customs regularly check people trying to bring back a bit too much duty free.

Comment: There’s a whole section in that Wikipedia page about the status of the European micro states which gives plenty of details about the situation for Andorra, stating that they do have checks.

Comment: I read that section, and it's true if "border controls" includes border booths where no one checks anything.  Or checks only sometimes.  I didn't even see anyone on the way in or on the way out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andorra does perform border control to apply rules depending on the nationality of visitors. They have freedom of movement agreements in place but the border controls serves check which rules apply to visitors and also to impose limits in importation of industrial and agricultural products.

> Customs control on the border
>
> As well as checks on visas or passports for Andorra, customs checks
> are carried out on the border, as there are limits to the amount of
> agricultural and industrial products you can take across the border.
> For more information about these limits, visit the Andorra border and
> customs website, where you’ll also find their addresses and opening
> hours.

[Source](https://visitandorra.com/en/visitor-information/before-you-arrive/passport-visas-customs/)

PS: I actually have waited at both entry and exit borders a couple of years ago while driving in and out. If you made it through group transport, perhaps they arranged clearance another way but driving, they do ask for ID when arriving and exiting.

Comment: “Food and beverage exports are heavily controlled and every tourist is checked on the borders of the principality. The Andorra customs officials are a lot more rigid in enforcing the rules than their French and Spanish counterparts,” according to https://www.relocatetoandorra.com/living-in-andorra/  But still, no one even seemed to look at us on the way in or out.  I did go by bus, but there were no questions at the bus station, either.  I had a bicycle trailer that could have held a LOT of merchandise!